# Is it posssible to create a Line-Chart with only 2 values? - Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Imagine i have the following example:

```
var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                data: [1, 7],
                fill: false,
            }
```

...

Is it possible to only define the first and the last value like in 'data' to create a Linear Graph?
I need to achieve this, because the start and the end point will be changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave gaps in your data using `null`. To display your two values as first and last value you just need to fill all the values in between with `null`. Then you can use the option `spanGaps:true` to connect the first and last point.

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      data: [1, null, null, null, null, null, 7],
      fill: false,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    spanGaps: true,
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
try {
  new Chart(ctx, options);
} catch (e) {
  // There's a cross origin error happening in the snippet
  //console.log (e)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```